# Duplicate Value in Java Set

Tags: java, collections, set

Java Set can't have a duplicate value. This is my code:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
Collections.addAll(set, arr);
```

If array arr have elements having the same value, set will have duplicate string value, why is it happening?

Where did i miss? Should I iterate the array and use the add method?

=============================================================

Sorry, the above code works. I made a mistake in array arr. It's a whitespace thing.

Comment: What does `arr` contain?

Comment: Are you sure? Any chance of a complete, compilable example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Check whether the `String` contain any invisible char such as whitespace.

Comment: How do you know the strings in the array have duplicate values?

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake on the array.

Answer (score 4):

When I run the following code, it demonstrates that the set contains no duplicates:

```
class FunkTest
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Set<String> theHash = new HashSet<String>(); 

        String[] theArray = new String[] {
            "funky",
            "garbage",
            "funky",
            "stuff",
            "things",
            "item",
            "funky",
            "funky"
        };

        Collections.addAll(theHash, theArray);

        for (String thisItem : theHash) {
            System.out.println(thisItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
stuff 
funky 
item 
things 
garbage
```

There must be something different about your strings.

Comment: yeah, i made a mistake on the array.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the objects aren't actually equal, so they're not the same Object.  If you look at the javadocs for [java.util.HashSet.add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29), you'll see that the comparison to determine if an object is already there uses .equals().  Make sure you're 2 strings aren't different in any way that'd make String.equals() return false.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how this is happening since you are using Strings which has implemented equals properly.

The following code prints "1" for both arrays. Are you sure you are not making a mistake?

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Collections;
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] arr1 = new String[]{"one","one"};
        Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<String>();
        Collections.addAll(set1, arr1);
        System.out.println(set1.size());

        String[] arr2 = new String[]{"two",new String("two")};
        Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<String>();
        Collections.addAll(set2, arr2);
        System.out.println(set2.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake on the array. what should be done on my post if the problem is on the mistake of OP?

Comment: Here are some suggestions, @JRGalia - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17753/what-to-do-when-there-was-no-problem-at-all

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken. A `Set` will never contain a duplicate. No, you do not need to iterate and use the `add` method.

Go back and take another look. What value(s) are duplicated? What happens if you add the array to a `List<String>` instead?